# Intermittent workstations with no network connectivity

Tags: ip, cisco, dhcp, switch, vlan

I have a campus wide network with ~10 workstations around campus(not from the same switch) that can't connect to the internet/network, they are successfully acquiring an IP address from the DHCP server. I seem to be getting a couple users a day with this issue, starting last week.

Workstation IP scheme: 10.215.0.0 255.255.240.0
VLAN: 215

Troubleshooting steps with no change:
I've cleared the network/IP stack: netsh int ip reset, netsh winsock reset, which pulled a new IP from the DHCP server and same issue.
I've checked the hosts file and it's the default.
Disabled Windows Firewall.

Troubleshooting steps with limited success:
Changed VLAN from 215 to 225 at Switch and successfully connected to the internet/network. Switch back to 215 same issue comes back.
Added a USB NIC adapter and successfully connected to the internet/network on VLAN 215.

Thanks, let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: Is there anything that might be causing line interference? (i.e. RF near network cables)

Comment: I don't believe so, in most of these departments there is a computer right next to the one that isn't working with no issues.

Comment: What kind of router/firewall are you using and how is it configured?

Comment: A stupid thing I've tried that has worked: complete power off (unplug from the wall for 20 sec to let 5Vsb drain down). Some NICs will start dropping packets of specific types when they've been on for a long time, and they are powered even when the computer is off to support Wake On LAN.

Comment: We're using a SOPHOS UTM 9 firewall, what kind of information are you looking for the configuratin?

Comment: I left it unplugged for 5 minutes, same issue when I powered it back on.

Comment: I was going to work on adding an exception in the firewall to bypass the IP address of the workstation that had the issue today, but when I went to turn on the workstation with the issue it was working now.